# Keep focus on main window while doing lengthy operations

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application that calls a dll when user clicks on a button. This dll does very lengthy operations and while it does that, I cannot interact with the MainWindow, e.g scroll down the Datagrid logging some update messages, switch tabs etc. 
How can I keep the MainWindow activated while the dll is running ? I thought about a BackgroundWorker that constantly calls the `.Activate()` method whenever `Window.Deactivated` occurs, but wouldn't that be terribly resource-consuming and slow down the other dll that already takes a lot of time ?

I'm waiting for suggestions :)
Thank you

Comment: Is your application multithreaded? because it sounds like you're running your method in the UI thread which essentially freezes the application until  it has completed whatever it was doing.

Comment: Sounds like you need [Async/Await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) in your life.

Comment: Yeah look at what Mike Eason is pointing you. Async methods will save you.

Comment: It seems I am indeed doing my time-consuming operations in the UI thread, I am just using a background worker to update a progress bar. I will look into that and come back if I need help again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are running that lengthy operation in the UI thread. Try running it in a separate thread.

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(CallLengthyDllMethod);
    }

    private void CallLengthyDllMethod()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10000); // simulating lengthy operations
        MessageBox.Show("Done!");
    }
```

Comment: I used your method, combined with an async method and await statement and it works perfectly without slowing down the time-consuming process ! Thank you